# PMD LocalVariableCouldBeFinal still a valid rule when working with collection in lambda?

Tags: java, checkstyle, pmd

PMD Rule logged as **LocalVariableCouldBeFinal**

I have a utility to derive the adjacent nodes, which would be populated based on the filtration and business code.

Code below clearly communicate the intent that the set would be populated later on.

Thus, this rule still holds true? For any such instances of use of collection in code irrespective of whether this is local variable or not?

```
public static Set<String> getAdjacentNodes(final Set<String> nodes) {
    final Set<String> nodesLocal = nodes.stream()
            .map(node -> node.toUpperCase())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    //PMD Complaining on below line of adjacentNodeSet : LocalVariableCouldBeFinal 
    Set<String> adjacentNodeSet = new HashSet<>();
    nodesLocal.stream()
            .forEach(node -> adjacentNodeSet.addAll(getAdjacentNodes(node)));

    Set<String> adjNodeList = adjacentNodeSet
            .stream()
            .filter(nodeId -> !(nodesLocal.contains(nodeId)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return adjNodeList;
}
```

Comment: `final` means you never assign a new value to `adjacentNodeSet`. It's not about immutable collections. I'd also rather use sth like `nodesLocal.stream().flatMap(n -> getAdjacentNodes(n).stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet())` rather than a forEach

Comment: @zapl I think you can re-factor this even further: `return nodes.stream()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .flatMap(n -> getAdjacentNodes(n).stream())
            .filter(n -> !(nodes.contains(nodeId.toLowerCase())))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *hate* this rule (may be it's time for me to look into disabling it in our project also). Well, first the error message says that it *could* be final, not that it *must* be final, that's like a tiny recommendation, not a rule per-se.

Especially since your variable is *effectively final* anyway, I would suppress this warning, or better (may be) get rid of it entirely (not sure PMD allows this).

But you could get around that with a simple refactor:

```
return nodes.stream()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .flatMap(n -> getAdjacentNodes(n).stream())
            .filter(nodeId -> !(nodes.contains(nodeId.toLowerCase())))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Yeah, same view would suppress this rule however, the refactoring you suggested is cleaner would try to use it for further Testing. Thank you

Comment: Lambda variables are not effectively final and *CAN* be reassigned within the lambda (unlike resources in try-with-resources which **are** final even if not using the keyword). Non the less, this seems like a legit exception to the rule (just like Lambdas are legit exceptions to the ShortVariable name). I'd suggest either setting up an `violationSuppressXPath` to ignore lambda vars, and open an issue on https://github.com/pmd/pmd to consider ignoring lambdas by default

Comment: @Johnco so `nodesLocal.stream()
            .forEach(node -> adjacentNodeSet.addAll(getAdjacentNodes(node)));` I was referring to  `adjacentNodeSet` being effectively final, not sure what you are though